# How can I test gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I've finally manage to make it work so that when you push to a branch job would launch, but I keep waiting for it to launch around 3min and then I've got errors which I need to fix and then commit again, and then waiting again. How can I just ssh to that public runner and test `.gitlab-ci.yml` "script" part just in the bash?

Comment: There is an online validator which does not only check if your configuration is correct, it also shows you **in which line there is a problem**! https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See if [GitLab 13.3](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/08/22/gitlab-13-3-released/#better-linting-for-gitlab-ciyml-files) (August 2020) could help:

> ### Better linting for `.gitlab-ci.yml` files
>
> When reviewing your CI definitions, you can now use our CI linter to go deeper into pipeline processing to validate the correctness of your `.gitlab-ci.yml`.
>
> The CI linter provides feedback not only for syntax validation, but it also validates other kinds of logical errors and invalid configurations by simulating the pipeline as if you were running on master (without actually running anything).
>
> This helps you produce a properly configured pipeline faster and helps you avoid situations where a pipeline passed the linter but still could not run.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#validate-the-gitlab-ciyml) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/229794).

And, still with [GitLab 13.3](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/08/22/gitlab-13-3-released/#ci-linter-now-can-provide-warnings-in-addition-to-errors) (August 2020)

> ### CI linter now can provide warnings in addition to errors
>
> The CI linter can now provide warnings in addition to error messages when validating your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.
>
> This gives us the opportunity to provide more guidance when evaluating your pipelines, thereby making it easier to avoid more kinds of mistakes by catching them earlier.
>
> Our initial iteration is to provide a warning when the `when:always` rule is used without `workflow:rules`; this scenario causes duplicate pipelines when an MR is created and has also been a source of confusion.
> And in addition to displaying this new warning message on the linter page, it will also appear on the pipeline view and run pipeline page to help you improve your CI configurations.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#validate-the-gitlab-ciyml) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/219431).

---

With [GitLab 13.8](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/01/22/gitlab-13-8-released/#cicd-configuration-validation-in-pipeline-editor) (January 2021), you can check its validity:

> ### CI/CD configuration validation in Pipeline Editor
>
> Previously, to validate your CI/CD configuration, you had to navigate to the CI lint page or commit your changes and look for any errors.
>
> In this release, we’ve added verification in the pipeline editor itself.
>
> It continuously checks your pipeline configuration before writing your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file and provides you with an indicator that your configuration is valid.
> This saves you time and effort that could otherwise be spent optimizing your pipeline.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_8/config_val.png -- CI/CD configuration validation in Pipeline Editor]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipeline_editor/index.html#validate-ci-configuration) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/292231).

---

See also [GitLab 13.12](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/05/22/gitlab-13-12-released/#pipeline-status-widget-in-the-pipeline-editor) (May 2021)

> ### Pipeline status widget in the pipeline editor
>
> Previously, after committing changes using the pipeline editor, you had to navigate to a different page to know the real time status of your pipeline.
>
> In this release, we added a pipeline status widget to the pipeline editor so that you can monitor the status of your pipeline without leaving the comfort of the editor.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_12/status.png -- Pipeline status widget in the pipeline editor]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipeline_editor/index.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/280829).

Comment: Thanks for updating this, as I was coming back to this issue once in a while.

Answer (score 80):

If you want to go beyond mere *linting* and **actually run** your CI script, you can do so using `gitlab-runner`. Here's how to do it.

## Install `gitlab-runner`

```
OS=darwin
#OS=linux # Uncomment on linux
sudo curl --output /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner https://gitlab-runner-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/binaries/gitlab-runner-${OS}-amd64
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner
```

<sup>Official gitlab-runner docs [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/)</sup>

## Create a command

The following `.gitlab-ci.yml` file defines a task named `build`:

```
build:
  script:
    - echo "Hello World"
```

## Run the command locally <sup>[(*limitations apply!*)](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/index.html#limitations-of-gitlab-runner-exec)</sup>

```
gitlab-runner exec shell build
```

When I run the above locally, I get the following output:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.3.1~beta.4.g0aa5179e (0aa5179e)
Using Shell executor...
Running on cory-klein.local...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/Users/coryklein/code/prometheus-redis-exporter/builds/0/project-0'...
done.
Checking out 66fff899 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ echo "Hello World"
Hello World
Job succeeded
```

Comment: This was very useful to me.  As the OP said: linting is sometimes not enough, as it won't detect logical errors you have made in the scripts or variables or ... In my eyes, your answer deserves the green check mark. :-)

Comment: OK, but what I really want to do is run the gitlab CI process *exactly as it runs on the server*.  Isn't there a preset to do that?  Good user interface practice is to make the most common use case the easiest to do.  That's just sane ergonomics.

Answer (score 65):

For the record: You can also copy paste your `gitlab-ci.yml` into the linter-form provided by gitlab:

[image]

Depending on which IDE you are using you might be able to find plugins that check for validity. For example in VS Code you can use a plugin called [gitlab-vscode-extension](https://about.gitlab.com/2018/03/01/gitlab-vscode-extension/) which can validate your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

In case you want to programatically validate your `.gitlab-ci.yml`, gitlab [provides an API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/lint.html#validate-the-gitlab-ciyml-api) which allows you to `POST` your yml to `/ci/lint`, e.g.:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/ci/lint --data '{"content": "{ \"image\": \"ruby:2.6\", \"services\": [\"postgres\"], \"before_script\": [\"bundle install\", \"bundle exec rake db:create\"], \"variables\": {\"DB_NAME\": \"postgres\"}, \"types\": [\"test\", \"deploy\", \"notify\"], \"rspec\": { \"script\": \"rake spec\", \"tags\": [\"ruby\", \"postgres\"], \"only\": [\"branches\"]}}"}'
```

Comment: That helps only partly. I'm not used to develop in production. I mean everything should be replicated somewhere before putting it to prod.

Comment: Can be found: `Projects > SampleProject > CD/CI > Pipelines`

Comment: The linter form provided by gitlab is completly useless. It tells you there is a problem , but not what problem, and not where.

Comment: Linting is not testing. A linter checks static aspects like syntax or any other kind of constraints or rules. Testing means to check the behaviour at runtime. 

IMHO the persons, who started this topic would like to be able to perform a kind of unit tests for a pipeline. In a complex setup, testing a pipeline manually is hard, boring and consumes a lot of time. Furthermore you are always in danger to break the logic you implemented quite easily, as you don't have any easy and fast way to run all tests to avoid any regression in your pipeline infrastructure.

Answer (score 34):

You can run builds locally (if you control the runner that is) by using the `gitlab-runner exec` command as described in the [official docs here](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/index.html#gitlab-runner-exec).

Make sure you also check the [limitations](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/index.html#limitations-of-gitlab-runner-exec) of testing jobs this way.

Answer (score 15):

The correct answer is that you cannot test your build pipeline without committing source code to your repository.  You can only test one job - most likely the first job - of your build pipeline with gitlab-runner exec.

Since you cannot run multiple jobs you cannot chain any prepare or build steps with anything else.  There is no way to stop gitlab-runner from creating a clean checkout and destroying your prepare/build steps.

The best/only way to test is to create a branch and keep force pushing changes to .gitlab-ci.yml to it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip of create a branch and keep force pushing changes to .gitlab-ci.yml! I was messing up my developer branch.

Comment: it's amazing: I need to test changes before merging into master yet I can test my change of my gitlab-ci.yml only in master (workflow rules)

Comment: if your using the gitlab gui, this sucks because you cant amend your commits. (note i rarely ever use the gitlab gui but im working on another branch at the moment and frankly i dont want to stash them,  its alot of changes, and cant take the risk/or mental strain that takes at the moment (think stash save patch, and a few files that actually belong in another branch, having to merge master in  anyway, then threat of conflicts)

Answer (score 3):

## Use scripting and gitlab's API

My strategy consists on a [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) script which is commanded to run via git's `pre-commit` hook. Of course it can run on demand, it's an script.

> It's dificult to simulate a pipeline locally, specially for shared runners, but it isn't to lint the yaml configuration file to avoid fiddling.

It uses two [gitlab's API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/) endpoints to [lint the `.gitlab-ci.yml`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/lint.html):

- [`POST /ci/lint`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/lint.html#validate-the-ci-yaml-configuration)
- [`POST /projects/:id/ci/lint`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/lint.html#validate-a-ci-yaml-configuration-with-a-namespace)

Both API calls depend on an `API_KEY`, which I setup within my `$HOME` at `~/.gitlab.env`. The script sources that file to load the key on its environment.

The project based endpoint also requires the project ID. It could be extracted from `git remote -v` and the like, but [for simplicity](https://wiki.c2.com/?KissPrinciple) it's just declared on the script, which is source-controlled within project's respository.

```sh
cat script/lint-ci
```

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# vim:sw=2:ts=2:et:ft=sh
# Written by lorenzogrv. Feel free to share and reuse.

set -Eeuo pipefail

cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")/.."

fail () {
  echo "$@" >&2
  false
}

PROJECT_ID=XXXXXXXX

main () {
  # shellcheck disable=SC1090
  test -f ~/.gitlab.env && source ~/.gitlab.env

  test -v API_KEY || fail "API_KEY not defined"
  test -n "$API_KEY" || fail "API_KEY is empty"

  local filename="${1:-".gitlab-ci.yml"}"
  local response

  response="$(
    jq --null-input --arg yaml "$(<"$filename")" '{ content: $yaml }' \
    | http --check-status \
      POST https://gitlab.com/api/v4/ci/lint \
      "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $API_KEY"
  )"

  if ! test "$(jq '.status' <<<"$response")" != "valid"
  then
    echo "$filename is invalid CI/CD config!"
    jq <<<"$response"
    false
  else
    echo "$filename is valid CI/CD config"
    true
  fi >&2

  response="$(
    jq --null-input --arg yaml "$(<"$filename")" '{ content: $yaml }' \
    | http --check-status \
      POST https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$PROJECT_ID/ci/lint \
      "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $API_KEY"
  )"

  if jq 'if .valid then empty else ("" | halt_error(1)) end' <<<"$response"
  then
    echo "Project's CI/CD config is valid"
    true
  else
    echo "Project's CI/CD config is not valid"
    jq <<<"$response" .errors
    jq <<<"$response" .warnings
    false
  fi >&2
}

main "$@"
```

Please note the script has some dependencies:

- [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)
- [httpie](https://httpie.io/)

### Posible enhacements

- The project endpoint [can simulate pipeline creation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/lint.html#validate-a-projects-ci-configuration), if provided a `dry_run` boolean parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The excellent open source tool [gitlab-ci-local](https://github.com/firecow/gitlab-ci-local) allows you to run/test your gitlab-ci pipelines on your local machine.

You can lint/preview your `.gitlab-ci.yml` by running:

```
$ gitlab-ci-local --preview
```